# How to save a program's progress, and resume later?

Tags: process, suspend

You may know a lot of programs, e.g some password cracking programs, we can stop them while they're running, and when we run the program again (with or without entering a same input), they will be able to continue from where they have left. I wonder what kind of **technique** those programs are using?

[Edit] I am writing a program mainly based on recursion functions. Within my knowledge, I think it is incredibly difficult to save such states in my program. Is there any technique, somehow, saves the stack contents, function calls, and data involved in my program, and then when it is restarted, it can run as if it hasn't been stopped? This is just some concepts I got in my mind, so please forgive me if it doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's going to be different for every program. For something as simple as, say, a brute force password cracker all that would really need to be saved was the last password tried. For other apps you may need to store several data points, but that's really all there is too it: saving and loading the minimum amount of information needed to reconstruct where you were.

Another common technique is to save an image of the entire program state. If you've ever played with a game console emulator with the ability to save state, this is how they do it. A similar technique exists in Python with pickling. If the environment is stable enough (ie: no varying pointers) you simply copy the entire apps memory state into a binary file. When you want to resume, you copy it back into memory and begin running again. This gives you near perfect state recovery, but whether or not it's at all possible is highly environment/language dependent. (For example: most C++ apps couldn't do this without help from the OS or if they were built VERY carefully with this in mind.)

Comment: Wow, this is greatly informative. I will take a real careful look to it. Thanks so much. :D

Answer (score 2):

Use **Persistence**.

Persistence is a mechanism through which the life of an object is beyond programs execution lifetime.

Store the state of the objects involved in the process on the local hard drive using **serialization**.

- [Implement Persistent Objects with Java Serialization](http://www.devx.com/Java/Article/9931)

Comment: I will take me a bunch of time to understand what you say here :D. Thanks so much. I will dig it now.

Comment: I was caught programming and forgot i was supposed to attach a link. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you need to continually save state (i.e. where you are in your calculation).  This way, if you interrupt the probram, when it restarts, it will know it is in the middle of calculation, and where it was in that calculation.

You also probably want to have your main calculation in a separate thread from your user interface - this way you can respond to "close / interrupt" requests from your user interface and handle them appropriately by stopping / pausing the thread.

Answer (score 0):

For linux, there is a project named CRIU, which supports process-level save and resume. It is quite like hibernation and resuming of the OS, but the granularity is broken down to processes. It also supports container technologies, specifically Docker. Refer to http://criu.org/ for more information.